# Do we have a canonical question about custom resolutions with Wayland?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

I just saw *yet another* question about why xrandr isn't working to add a custom resolution after updating the OS, and I think we should have a canonical question about this.

Do we have a comprehensive answer about this yet?

Comment: Sounds like a good topic for a Canonical question.